# How to change Ant table header checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I have a table in my application, where I use select for each row.

When I click on and select row, on the top-left corner appears a checked checkbox. **I don't want to display that checkbox, I want to display something else**, a div with a text for example. That div should appear only when I click on a checkbox from a row.

How to do this? I tried to find the event that renders that checkbox, but I didn't manage. How to access that element and to change it in other else?  link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-ant-design-demo-vlftk?file=/index.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can set custom component to **columnTitle** inside props **rowSelection** of `<Table />`

> Set the title of the selection column
>   Type: string|React.ReactNode

Refer: document of [Antd Table rowSelection](https://ant.design/components/table/#rowSelection)

```
const rowSelection = {
  columnTitle: selectedRowKeys.length > 0 ? <div>XXX</div> : <></>,
  ...
}

<Table rowSelection={rowSelection} />;
```

[image]

Comment: Can we just change the tick mark in the select all checkbox to a '-' mark. If so how could i do it?

Comment: @keikai,  could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67882888/group-inputs-in-react-js